# How to claculate string column Sum in jasperReport

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I need to retrieve sum of a String column so i wrote this :

```
<variable name="totalQt" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Sum">
    <variableExpression>
      <![CDATA[Integer.parseInt($F{QTARTBP}.replaceAll(" ", ""))]]>

     </variableExpression>
</variable>
```

But i'm getting this error :

```
....
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:504)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
at   
 articleBonPreparation_1385730226859_237481.evaluateEstimated(articleBonPreparation_1385730226859_237481:428)

 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JREvaluator.evaluateEstimated(JREvaluator.java:254)
```

So there are empty string , so how to use zero in that case , i wrote thiw but it's wrong 
:

```
    <variableExpression>

      <![CDATA[$F{QTARTBP}.equals("") ? 0 : Integer.parseInt($F{QTARTBP}.replaceAll(" ", ""))]]>

    </variableExpression>
```

Any idea will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful to see what input data you are using, but despite that, it's clear that your code will fail if the value of `$F{QTARTBP}` is a single space (`" "`). You could try the following expression instead, which will include the single space in your empty string check and will return `0` instead:

```
$F{QTARTBP}.replaceAll(" ", "").equals("") ? 0 : Integer.parseInt($F{QTARTBP}.replaceAll(" ", ""))
```

You should be aware that this is will still fail if any of your input strings cannot be interpreted as an integer.

Answer (score -2):

Jasper are not to calculate - you should generate String in your java-code. And calculate what you need in java too.

Upd. This answer is incorrect. I learned JR more deeper and understand it.

Comment: Your answer is unclear. What do you mean `Jasper are not to calculate`?